# Double filter though nested ListView asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to use nested `ListViews` in my site navigation to make it dynamic. The goal is to make the first ListView show all categories then the nested one would show brands.

Hence if we had a product that we where selling you could click Sneakers for all Sneakers to populate and then a brand like Nike to filter only Nike Sneakers.

So far have been able to do this by Category(Sneakers) through passing in a query string. Now i want to pass in two parameters though that query string and the issue i am running into is that how can i pull the first value param from the parent `ListView` to add to the param of the nested `ListView`? Is this possible?

So brief explanation of why i am doing this. I have a products table that have a category and  brand attribute. I want to filter by category and brand and using these nested `ListViews` to pass the params.

```
   <asp:ListView ID="categoryList"
            ItemType="E_Store_Template.Models.Category"
            runat="server"
            SelectMethod="GetCategories">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink  runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%# GetCatValidUrl( Item.CategoryID ) %>"
                  ID="testlink" Text="<%#: Item.CategoryName %>" />

                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <li>
                       <asp:ListView ID="brandList" ItemType="E_Store_Template.Models.Brand" runat="server"
                            SelectMethod="GetProductsmain">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        //Below i cannot use Item.CategoryName
                                        //because of the Itemtype=my brand type.

                                <asp:HyperLink  runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%# GetCatBraValidUrl(Item.CategoryName, Item.BrandID) %>"
                  ID="testlink" Text="<%#: Item.BrandName %>" />

                                    </li>
                             </ul>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>

                </li>
                </ul>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

First time making one of these so any tips greatly appreciated. Even if this is the wrong way to do this i want to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you're code-behind, modify the

```
GetProductsmain()
```

to return a list based on the currently selected item in the

```
categoryList
```

[The respective ListView properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx)